# Android custom home for tablet

Tags: android

Im develping an app using apk 12 for 10.1 inch galaxy tablet. I would like to design a home screen only with my apps icon so that user will not be able to access anything else. Can I do that ? If yes, how ??

Comment: Found few things for phone with older apks. For ur knowledge lot many thing are diff for honeycomb. I would like to know for "honeycomb"

Comment: I'm aware of the differences. Your question still didn't contain any hint that you even tried to research something. And I won't base votes on "maybe he researched". Show it or get a suitable vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to design a home screen only with my apps icon so that user will not be able to access anything else. Can I do that ?

Yes, it is possible to create a home screen application.

> If yes, how ??

There is a Home sample app in your Android SDK installation (assuming you installed the samples from the SDK Manager). It largely boils down to having an activity with an `<intent-filter>` using `CATEGORY_HOME`.

Note that the user who installs your app will have the option of choosing between your home screen and the built-in one. Even if they make your home screen the default one, they will still be able to revert that decision by removing your app:

- by booting in safe mode
- via the Android SDK (e.g., `adb uninstall`)
- by getting into Settings through notifications and the like
- possibly other means

> For ur knowledge lot many thing are diff for honeycomb.

For your knowledge, nothing changed in this area with Android 3.0.